# Export DynamoDB Tables with dynamically generated names to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I am storing time series data in DynamoDB tables that are generated daily ([Example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/design-patterns-for-high-volume-time-series-data-in-amazon-dynamodb/)). The naming convention of the tables is "timeseries_2019-12-20", where 2019-12-20 takes the current days date. I want to send the previous days table to an S3 bucket in a CSV format. What is the recommended method for this? I was looking at AWS Glue but not seeing how to have it find the new table name each day. Maybe a lambda function with a cloudwatch event would be better? The DynamoDB tables are not large in size, a few hundred stored numbers.

Comment: Does the table name format stays same except for date i.e, timeseries_2019-12-20,timeseries_2019-12-21,timeseries_2019-12-22 ??

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy that is correct. I imagine there is a not so challenging way to do this but I am struggling to see it. Right now the daily tables are created by invoking a lambda function with AWS SAM and another lambda function is invoked which puts items to the table. Ideally I would like to have a third lambda function invoked through AWS SAM that exports the dynamo table to s3. So far I don't see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can achieve this by following below steps:

Assuming that you are using boto3(python) in lambda

1. Calculate yesterday's date using today's date.
2. Pass this date by adding prefix(matching table name) as DynamoDBTargets to Glue create/update crawler boto3 API call [[1]](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_crawler) and start the crawler.
3. Once crawler finishes creating table in Glue catalog then you can import it to Glue ETL and convert it to CSV.

Create a lambda trigger for DynamoDB table so that Glue crawler will be triggered or you can schedule the crawler to run at some point of time everyday.

Comment: Yeah this worked, I was getting hung up around step 2. Thanks!